# Check if array fields are empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to check if the fields in an array are empty. I would like to know if there is any function in PHP that does this. I've tried `empty()`, but since it checks if the array is empty, it returns false because the array has fields.

The following array is below:

```
"wm" => array:7 [▼
    "make" => null
    "model" => null
    "version" => null
    "portal_plan_id" => null
    "portal_highlight_id" => null
    "price_type_id" => null
    "announce" => null
  ]
```

See that the values are `null` and they are the ones I need to check.

Thank you!

Comment: i'm so sorry, I did not see that I was asking on the wrong website.

Comment: Do you need to know if every value is null or only specific ones?

Comment: every value @NMahurin

Comment: Which field do you want to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this depending on what you need. If you want to know if *any* values are null: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
array_search(null, $array)
```

The array_search will return false if no keys are null. So you can do

```
if(array_search(null, $array) !== false){
    // There is at least one null value
}
```

If you want to know which keys hold a null value:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
array_keys($array, null)
```

The array_keys will provide all keys that have a null value. So you can check

```
if(count(array_keys($array, null)) > 0){
    // There is at least one null value. array_keys($array, null) can retrieve the keys that are null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
     'make' => KIA,
     'model' => Koup,
     'version' => 5.0,
     'portal_plan_id' => null 
];

if(in_array(null, $array)){
    // do something
}
```

The above checks if there there is at least one null value, in this case it will evaluate to true

```
$array = [
   'make' => null,
   'model' => null,
   'version' => null,
   'portal_plan_id' => null  
];

if(count(array_unique($array)) == 1 && array_unique($array)['make'] == null)
{        
       //do something
}
```

Where ['make'] is your first index, you can pick any index. The above will evaluate to true. This is how it works; it checks if all values are the same(array_unique($array)) == 1) and if the first value is null (array_unique($array)['make'] == null). By logic if the first value is null and all values are the same, you can conclude that all values are null